# Output of discrete-time survival model interpretation

Tags: r, time-series, anova, generalized-linear-model, survival

I have a question regarding the output from a discrete-time survival model that I have previously asked questions about [here][1].

The code looks the following (see link further up for more info):

```
mod<-glm(Mating_time ~ Round + A*B,data=dat, family=binomial(link="cloglog"))

Anova(mod)

> Anova(mod)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: as.factor(Mating_time)
                        LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Round                     35.094  8  2.571e-05 ***
A                          3.749  2    0.15343    
B                          9.024  2    0.01097 *  
A : B                     10.424  4    0.03385 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 

multcomp::cld(emmeans(Mating_time, ~A|B), Letters = letters, reversed = T) # Post-Hoc test

> multcomp::cld(emmeans(Mating_time, ~A|B), Letters = letters, reversed = T) # Post-Hoc test
B = Metabolite:
 A           emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL .group
 Normal       -1.87 0.218 Inf     -2.29     -1.44  a    
 Metabolite   -1.98 0.192 Inf     -2.35     -1.60  a    
 Low          -1.99 0.217 Inf     -2.42     -1.57  a    

B = Normal:
 A           emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL .group
 Low          -1.49 0.213 Inf     -1.91     -1.08  a    
 Normal       -2.35 0.249 Inf     -2.84     -1.86   b   
 Metabolite   -2.59 0.264 Inf     -3.10     -2.07   b   

B = Low:
 A           emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL .group
 Normal       -2.26 0.230 Inf     -2.71     -1.81  a    
 Low          -2.55 0.265 Inf     -3.07     -2.03  a    
 Metabolite   -2.62 0.236 Inf     -3.09     -2.16  a    

Results are averaged over the levels of: Round 
Results are given on the cloglog (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Note: contrasts are still on the cloglog scale 
Results are given on the as.factor (not the response) scale. 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 
significance level used: alpha = 0.05 
NOTE: If two or more means share the same grouping symbol,
      then we cannot show them to be different.
      But we also did not show them to be the same.
```

I know that ANOVA and post-hoc tests such as Tukey's test can give different output since they are different tests that answers different questions. However, the output I get is somewhat confusing to me. I do see significance of B and A : B interaction (also round but that's less important to what I'm actually interested in, I'm interested in how A and B and their interaction influences mating_time). Due to the way we structured our research question, we do pairwise comparisons by B (three comparisons for the three groups formed). However, the output I get from the ANOVA says that there's significance for B and the interaction A : B. However, when I do the post-hoc test I would suspect all comparisons being the same because of this. Although I see differences in the "B normal" group, this I would expect to be the case if A on ANOVA showed significance. I can't wrap my head around how this could be the case if just B and A : B interaction showed significance.

EDIT:

When I try to run type 1 SS anova (either with anova() command or aov()) on the model I run into the following error that I can't find no correction for online.

```
> test<-aov(mod)
Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
> summary(test)
Error in levels(x)[x] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

Works with Anova type II and III though. Any thoughts?

Comment: `aov()` is a function for *fitting* a model. I think you meant `anova()` or `car::Anova()`

Comment: I tried with both aov() then summary on the aov model that I created as seen above. Should do the trick if I'm not mistaken but I get the error code. Also for the anova() I get the same error as for aov().

With Car::Anova() I can only do type II or III anova and not type I as with anova(), hence the reason I try to run it. You mentioned in an earlier comment that type II anova ignore the interaction

Answer (score 0):

A significant interaction means that the combination of two treatments has a different effect than you would predict based on the effects of the treatments individually. In the calculations, the interaction term is represented by the *product* of the predictor values, as coded.

Interactions are thus inherently symmetric. You can express the interaction equivalently as either "the effect of `B` depends on the level of `A`" or "the effect of `A` depends on the level of `B`." In your type of display, you might expect to find something like what you show regardless of whether you evaluated levels of `A` within levels of `B` (as you show) or the other way around.

In your data, `A` has no effect when `B = Metabolite` or `B = Low`. You could predict those values just on the basis of the value of `B`. For those treatment combinations, the value of `A` doesn't matter.

When `B = Normal`, however, you can't predict the combinations with either an effect of `B` (ignoring `A`) alone, or an effect of `A` (ignoring `B`) alone. That's why you had a significant interaction term: there were situations in which you couldn't adequately predict the outcomes based on separate effects of `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Anova` results express type 2 tests. That means that the test of `A` is based on the model with just `A` and `B`, and *not* `A:B`. That is, when you completely ignore the interaction of `A` and `B`, the marginal effect of `A` is not all that big.

I also suggest that you spend more effort *looking* at what you have and less effort on shopping for P values. A graph like `emmip(Mating_time, A ~ B)` should be helpful for understanding what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the input on the ANOVA, so I would rather go for either type I or III. 

I've plotted the data according to the emmip(Mating_time, A ~ B). Would you suggest to look at contrasts to see where the effects are located in a following manner:

mod.int <- emmeans(mod, ~A*B) # look at contrasts
mod.int 

I'm asking since if I'm interested in the interaction effect, I should have some statistics to report the least. In my field, people seems to include interaction effects in the model (and run type 2 anovas as I have seen) but don't report statistics further than ANOVA output.

Comment: I would do `emm.int <- emmeans(mod, ~A|B)` then `pairs(emm.int)` and `pairs(emm.int, by = "A")`. In other words, simple comparisons of A for each B and of B for each A. If people in your field don't report things past anova output, then shame on them because they are star-gazing for `*`'s but not bothering to try to understand what they have.

Comment: Thanks, so a possible way to report the results from the comparisons of A for each B and B for each A in a figure could be to use capital letters for lets say A for each B and small letters for B in each A? I'm creating figures based on the estimated marginal means and the SE given by the model.

Comment: Another comment on the subject, i looked into this forum post [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/586240/emmeans-interaction-contrasts) where you suggested looking at contrasts of contrasts, in the case I have an interaction effect, this would also be suggested right? From my knowledge, code you wrote above looks at A for each B and vice versa. But since I also have the interaction effect, after running ANOVA (type III) I'll go for comparisons suggested above and the contrasts of contrasts to see where the interaction effects are present?

Comment: Made an edit in the post regarding the type I ANOVA. I receive an error while running it. This doesn't happen with type 2 or 3 from Anova() command though.